# How can I send from Hotmail with a different from address

Tags: outlook.com, email-forwarding

I have set up an email forwarder, from let's say `jon@example.com` to `jon@hotmail.com`. Jon wants to be able to send email from within hotmail that appears to come from `jon@example.com`. How can you do this?

(A quick web search didn't turn up anything - it's a bit hard to think of good search terms for this particular question ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you're in the inbox view, `Options (in the top right) -> More Options -> Send and receive mail from other e-mail accounts`

You can then add another email address through the interface, which then sends a confirmation email with a confirmation link.

One thing to note though is that your `@hotmail.com` address is used in the `Sender:` mail header though to ensure it's delivered, which means that any delivery reports will probably come back to `@hotmail` rather than `@example`, and some programmes will print the sender as `x@hotmail.com on behalf of y@example.com`

Comment: I cannot find this option. Can you tell me where it is located now ?

Answer (score 1):

From within Hotmail, select

- `Options` (top right) than `More Options`.
- Choose, `Send and receive mail from other e-mail accounts`

then at the bottom you can follow the instructions for setting up another account to send email from.

One thing to note is that it may say `From jon@hotmail.com on behalf of jon@example.com` when sending the email.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial with 7 easy steps to walk you through it:

http://www.googez.com/2011/04/send-email-from-other-accounts-using-hotmail/